# Variadic template function where return type depends on template argument list

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic

I am getting a "wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)" error that I can't really understand.

I have a class that provides some helper function for other types that want to interact with it, setting a first template parameter on which they must agree to be compatible with each other automatically on creation. In order to do this in a convenient, general way, I decided to go for a variadic template, that is intended to both be passed constructor arguments and additional template arguments the object type that is to be created takes:

```
template<typename INTERNAL_TYPE>
class Linker
{
  template< template<typename, typename ...> class INPUT_OBJ_TYPE, class ... TEMPLATE_ARGS, class ... CONSTRUCTOR_ARGS >
  std::shared_ptr< INPUT_OBJ_TYPE<INTERNAL_TYPE,TEMPLATE_ARGS ...> > getLinked( CONSTRUCTOR_ARGS ... args )
  {
    std::shared_ptr< INPUT_OBJ_TYPE<INTERNAL_TYPE,TEMPLATE_ARGS ...> > ptr = std::make_shared< INPUT_OBJ_TYPE<INTERNAL_TYPE,TEMPLATE_ARGS ...> >( args... );
    return ptr;
  }
};
```

This works for the following class:

```
template<typename INTERNAL_TYPE, typename SECOND_TYPE>
class TEST_CLASS_1
{};
```

That is, I can do the following:

```
Linker<int> container;
auto test_1 = container.getLinked<TEST_CLASS_1,double>();
```

Then I tried to do the same with another class that is only templated on one argument:

```
template<typename INTERNAL_TYPE>
class TEST_CLASS_2
{};
auto test_2 = container.getLinked<TEST_CLASS_2>();
```

But get the above mentioned error.. Why? Playing around with the code I figured as much as that it would compile for the second test (no more for the first one though) if I removed TEMPLATE_ARGS from the function declaration/definition. So I figured that the compiler at that point does not yet realize TEMPLATE_ARGS is empty for the second test and throws an error for having too many template arguments. So I thought I might need to use a trailing return type like

```
template< template<typename, typename ...> class INPUT_OBJ_TYPE,
          class ... TEMPLATE_ARGS, class ... CONSTRUCTOR_ARGS >
auto getLinked( CONSTRUCTOR_ARGS ... args )
    -> std::shared_ptr< INPUT_OBJ_TYPE<TREE_TYPE,TEMPLATE_ARGS ...> >
```

or using `decltype` but that didn't work either:

```
template< template<typename, typename ...> class INPUT_OBJ_TYPE,
          class ... TEMPLATE_ARGS, class ... CONSTRUCTOR_ARGS >
auto getLinked( CONSTRUCTOR_ARGS ... args )
    ->decltype(std::shared_ptr< INPUT_OBJ_TYPE<TREE_TYPE,TEMPLATE_ARGS ...> >())
```

Am I right about the problem? And how can I solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a compiler bug.

A way to get what you want is to provide two functions, your original and another that doesn't have the non-deducible parameter pack:

```
template<typename INTERNAL_TYPE>
struct Linker
{
    template<
        template<typename, typename ...> class INPUT_OBJ_TYPE,
        class ... TEMPLATE_ARGS,
        class ... CONSTRUCTOR_ARGS
    >
    std::shared_ptr<
        INPUT_OBJ_TYPE<INTERNAL_TYPE,TEMPLATE_ARGS...>
    > getLinked( CONSTRUCTOR_ARGS ... args )
    {
        std::shared_ptr< INPUT_OBJ_TYPE<INTERNAL_TYPE,TEMPLATE_ARGS...> > ptr =
          std::make_shared< INPUT_OBJ_TYPE<INTERNAL_TYPE,TEMPLATE_ARGS...> >( args... );
        return ptr;
    }

    template<
        template<typename, typename ...> class INPUT_OBJ_TYPE,
        class ... CONSTRUCTOR_ARGS
    >
    std::shared_ptr<
        INPUT_OBJ_TYPE<INTERNAL_TYPE>
    > getLinked( CONSTRUCTOR_ARGS ... args )
    {
        std::shared_ptr< INPUT_OBJ_TYPE<INTERNAL_TYPE> > ptr =
          std::make_shared< INPUT_OBJ_TYPE<INTERNAL_TYPE> >( args...);
        return ptr;
    }
};
```

Comment: A parameter pack not otherwise deduced is deduced as an empty pack.

Comment: @T.C.:  That's only for a trailing parameter pack isn't it?

Comment: @VaughnCato This is what I'm doing at the moment to keep going. I'm surprised that the compiler is not able to deduce that since only INPUT_OBJ_TYPE is given, both following parameter packs must necessarily be empty. Is there any reason for this that I don't see? Having just the one function would be much nicer...

Comment: @bluewater2: It's an odd case.  I think it would be possible to modify the standard to support what you want.  Currently it only allows the trailing parameter pack to be deduced, but it seems like it could be changed to allow the last non-deduced parameter pack to be deduced as empty.

Comment: I'm not really convinced that "trailing" has the meaning you are ascribing to it (`template<class T, class U> void f(T t, U u);`; `f(0, 1)` is OK and `T` counts as "trailing" - the rule is "Trailing template arguments that can be deduced ([temp.deduct]) or obtained from default template-arguments may be omitted from the list of explicit template-arguments."), and I'm not convinced that this is the cause of the error OP is seeing, either; if you keep the `TEMPLATE_ARGS` pack, and just not use it in the return type, it compiles.

Comment: @T.C.: That's an interesting point about it working if you remove the return type.  It does seem inconsistent.  I don't get your point about your `f(0,1)` example though, since both `T` and `U` are deduced from the function arguments.

Comment: @VaughnCato Yes, but the rule is that you can only omit "trailing" template arguments. Clearly `T` counts as "trailing".

Comment: @T.C.: I see your point.  Based on that, trailing would mean any parameters that were not explicitly specified.  Are you thinking it is a compiler bug?

Comment: That's what I'm leaning toward, but I know that compilers can be a bit lax in this area, so not completely sure right now.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the initial substitution of `TEST_CLASS_2` is hitting the compiler's "every valid specialization requires an empty pack" code path - that is, the following template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required:

```
template<class... TArgs, class... CArgs>
std::shared_ptr<TEST_CLASS_2<INTERNAL_TYPE, TArgs...>> getLinked( CArgs... args )
{
   /* ... */
}
```

because every valid specialization of it requires `TArgs` to be an empty pack. The initial substitution into `getLinked` will indeed result in something similar, but of course, you didn't actually write that template, so I'm not convinced that there should be an error, but whatever.

A possible workaround is to defer substitution of `INPUT_OBJ_TYPE` until after deduction, by taking a tag type and making everything deduced:

```
template< template<class, class...> class, class... > struct tag {};

template< template<class, class...> class INPUT_OBJ_TYPE,
          class... TArgs, class... CArgs >
auto getLinked(tag<INPUT_OBJ_TYPE, TArgs...>, CArgs... args )
    -> std::shared_ptr<INPUT_OBJ_TYPE<INTERNAL_TYPE,TArgs...>> 
{
    /* ... */
}
```